# OpenGL visual studiio 2010 C++ Windows7 Runtime error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opengl, windows-7-x64

I just got a new 64-bit computer with the characteristics in the title above and am trying to run a simple OpenGL program with only glutInit() and return 0 in main() .  It builds but running under Debug opens a window with a black screen and then another popup window which says "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).  Click OK to close the application."  I've rechecked the placing of the .h, .lib and .dll files and they match suggestions I've found online.  I think my project settings are correct or it wouldn't have built. What did I forget to do?

Comment: Have you checked whether you are mixing 32 and 64 bit libraries? Maybe you are compiling your app for 64 bits, but your glut is 32 bits...

Comment: Did you install proper graphics drivers? The drivers preinstalled with Windows 7 are crippled and lack proper OpenGL support. Please visit your GPU maker's website and download their official, complete driver package.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your comments, but I've been using freeglut and have put the x64 version in both systemWOW64 and the Microsoft SDKs bin folder.  Also I did go to the NVidia site and get a driver for my GTX 660 card.  Though I didn't mention it in the post, I also tried disabling my antivirus (AVG) and firewall (Comodo) for a trial run and those changes didn't help.  Any other possibilities?  Thanks, Stig

Comment: Placing a 64 bit library in WOW64 is not right. WOW64 should have 32 bit libraries and executables only. WOW64 stands for Win32 Over Windows 64.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small getting-started program for OpenGL 3.2 (or later) using Visual Studio 2010 and FreeGlut / GLEW.

https://github.com/mortennobel/OpenGL_3.2_VS_2010_freeglut

One important points to notice is to set `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;` (otherwise the program can crash on some OpenGL drivers).